# no such column: blog_post.title

Tags: python, html, django, blogs

[image]

I cant figure out what is wrong, I am getting the following error:

> < OperationalError at /blog/ no such column: blog_post.title Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ Django Version: 1.10.5 Exception Type: OperationalError Exception Value: no such column: blog_post.title Exception Location: C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35- 32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 337 Python Executable: C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Vmoney\Desktop\Scripts\mysite\python.exe Python Version: 3.5.2 Python Path:

Here is the template:

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
        <h5>{{ post.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}<a href="/blog/{{post.id}}">  {{ post.title }}</a></h5>
    {% endfor %}
{% block content %} 

{% for post in object_list %} 
{{ post.date|date:"Y-m-d" }} 
{{ post.title }} 
{% endfor %} 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Show us the models.py code of POST model.

Comment: from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

Answer (score 2):

You might forgot to `makemigrations` and `migrate`.
do like this:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```